# Maven with Nexus cannot read zip file

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a maven project which is giving me BUILD FAILURE with the following error when I try to run `mvn clean package install`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5:compile (default-compile) on project common-web: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\thomas\.m2\repository\org\project\project-framework-utils-1.0.22.jar; cannot read zip file
```

I already see all the dependencies under Maven Dependencies in my project in Eclipse. Could someone help me understand why am I getting this error?

I deleted files in `.m2 repository`, but did not help me.

When I go to nexus via internet browser, I can download .jar file and open it.

Comment: Check if you can read its contents with the Java `jar` command: `jar tf C:\Users\thomas\.m2\repository\org\project\project-framework-utils-1.0.22.jar`

Comment: I have an error: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Comment: So Java's zip classes are not able to process it. Try deleting the one in Nexus and replacing it with a newly built one, or, if that's not possible, unzipping and rezipping it.

Comment: I can not replace jar in nexus, so I replace jar to zip on my disk and try unzipping but I got cpgz file, what is it?

Comment: NB.. you should not package and install since install automatically calls package